# security configuration with spting boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am new at Spring
Can someone explain to me the role of these two methods (loadUserByUsername and configure) ?
I am trying to understand spring security

```
@Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(myAuthenticationProvider);
    }
@Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        UserBuilder builder = null;
        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
        if (user==null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(email);
        }else{
            builder = org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User.withUsername(email);
            builder.password(user.getPassword());
            builder.roles(user.getRole());
        }
        return builder==null ? null : builder.build();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UserDetailsService` bean is used by the `DaoAuthenticationProvider` to retrieve user information in order to authenticate them. It is a core interface inside Spring Security.

The `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)` method can be used to expose the resulting `AuthenticationManager` as a bean. You can do something like:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth
        // enable in memory based authentication with a user named
        // "user" and "admin"
        .inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER").and()
                .withUser("admin").password("password").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
}
```

Although, you can achieve the same as above by doing:

```java
@Bean
UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    UserDetails user = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder().username("test").password("password")
        .roles("ROLE_USER").build();
    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
}
```

Be aware that the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` class [has been deprecated](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter) in Spring Security 5.7.0-M2, thus not being recommended anymore. The blog post provide more detail on that.

Comment: so it's loadUserByUsername which verifies the authentication of the user?

Comment: It's just a core interface to load the user. The authentication itself depends on what you are using for authentication. I recommend to take a look at the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/dao-authentication-provider.html).